# $O(\ln(\ln n))$ rounds to achieve $(\ln n)^4$ players

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I'm reading a paper on [Randomized Rumor Spreading](http://archive.cone.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/pubs/rumor.pdf) and I'm confused about part 2.1. *startup phase* (page 4).

We try to spread a message ("rumor") using a push-scheme, where each informed player calls a random player in each round and sends the message. At the beginning of the first round only one player holds the rumor. If we execute *c* rounds then probability that this player has at least once called an uninformed player (i.e., didn't call itself) is $1-n^{-c}$, where *n* is the number of players in the network. So the number of informed players doubles each round with high probability, when the number of informed nodes is small.

The next step is confusing to me.
How does it follow from the fact that it takes at most *c* rounds to double the number of informed nodes, that it takes at most $O(\ln(\ln n))$ rounds to achieve $(\ln n)^4$ players?

Comment: Please try to make your question self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I now added some more context to the question.

Comment: Please respect the time of your readers. Don't expect us to read through the paper ourselves to hunt down what you are talking about. Give page numbers. Define all your symbols (that are not common: we know that $O(\cdot)$ means). In particular, what is $n$? Be careful of your wording - as stated, the claim is obviously false. From the second round onwards, there is a small chance that the two informed players keep calling each other. and thus the number of informed players never increases, so $(\ln n)^4$ would never be achieved. I suspect the paper is more circumspect in their claim.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment Paul. *n* is the number of players in the network; I edited it to my question now. The claim is true when the number of informed players is small enough, so the probability of two players calling each other is sufficiently small. Apparently the boundary for this is $(\ln n)^4$ informed players, but this is also unclear from the paper.